# Does deleting a file in Safari downloads also deletes it in Files app?

Tags: ipad, ipados, mobile-safari, files.app

This morning (Sat Mar 18 2023), I downloaded a very important file to Safari downloads (shows an circle with a down arrow in it in the toolbar next to the address bar).

[image]

I have read it (it's a .docx) in Files app and then, when I came back to Safari, I saw the icon mentionned above, and I wanted to remove it (it takes more place then when it's not here, obviously. It's more relevant because I'm also using slide-over with 2 Safari windows a lot).

Since there is no "Customize Toolbar" button as in Mail or Numbers apps, I'm looking for a way to hide this icon. The only way to me would be to delete the file that has been downloaded because this icon popped at the same time I downloaded the file, so I guess removing it would cause the icon to go away.

I have finished reading this file but I will need it after on for a quite significant amount of time.

Also, I cannot re-download it because took it from a link posted in the chat of a Zoom meeting, and therefore cannot re-access it. Indeed, I moved this .docx file to one of my folders, to be sure to find it again but it hasn't moved from the Safari in-app downloads (the icon is still there too).

So, since this is an important file and I don't want risking to lose it (haven't tried deleting yet, I want a confirmation), **does deleting it in Safari app also deletes it in Files app?**

[image]

*Note: I'm on iPad 6th gen running iPadOS 16.2*

Comment: Why not download anything else und just delete that one to see what happens? Or moving the important file to a better place than the Downloads directory?

Comment: @nohillside Well, I don't want to risk anything because as I said in the question, this is an important file. Also, I cannot re-download it because took it from a link posted in the chat of a Zoom meeting, and cannot re-access that link. Indeed, I moved this docx to one of my folders, to be sure to find it again but it hasn't moved from the Safari in-app downloads (the icon is still there too).

Comment: How are you “deleting” a file from Safari?

Comment: @Allan See the second screenshot of the question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvHtC.jpg). I just click "Delete" but for the test file. To do this, you need to slightly swipe the file left and it will reveal the option.

Comment: That’s the download *list*; not a file manager.

Comment: @Allan Why is this called a download list and the Safari downloads? I don't have any file named Safari Downloads in Files.app. Anyhow, I corrected in the question

Answer (score 1):

> does deleting it in Safari app also deletes it in Files app?

#### Yes.  The Files App only *organizes and manages* files.

You don’t download anything to the Files app.

I’m seen this question and phrasing several times already so, I wanted to address it. The ***The Files App is used to manage files, you don’t download to it.***

From the description of the [Files App in the App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/files/id1232058109):

> **Access and organize your files** no matter where they’re located — on your device, in the cloud, on an external drive or file server— with Files.

Think of Files as being like Finder with Preview or Windows Explorer.  You use it to manage and organize your files and can even open them up with the associated application.  If you delete a file though an app like Safari, Word, or Numbers, you delete the file from the *system*; the Files app will only reflect that change. Likewise for copies and moves.

Comment: I have moved the file to a specific folder in files and still the icon and the file is still shown in Safari. Also, what do you mean by "You don't download anything to the Files app"? There is a button "Save to files" normally, doesn't it download the file in Files then?

Comment: Save to files (lowercase) saves it either locally or to iCloud.  If using Firefox, Chrome or Edge it will save it to their local downloads directory.   Why not take nohillside’s advice and download a random file, delete it and see what happens in Files?

Comment: As for the what you are seeing in Safari, it’s a *list* of recently downloaded files. Why not try tapping on the link and see what happens.   You said you moved the file, right?  Do one better and email it as an attachment to yourself. Then start experimenting rather than debating this ad nauseam.

Comment: Ok, adding edits to the question.

Comment: I am testing and adding the results of my tests as an edit to the question. I'm almost done with the tests I can think of and the ones proposed.

Comment: @Thinkr Hi and welcome. you're making a common mistake in complicating your question. It should have the bare minimum of details to allow someone to know the problem you face. All your experimentation, possible solutions, etc... belong more properly in an answer. That's where blog post, detailed explanations, how you show your answer is correct (or incorrect / partial / work in progress - all are very welcome here in the ANSWER section).

Comment: Ok. Do I need to make an answer then? @bmike

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a file, use the clear button in iOS / iPadOS safari to not risk deleting the file. Since the Apple OS use file handles, when you move a file, it is still the same file so deleting it could cause you pain.

For extra protection, get / borrow a Mac and use Time Machine to back up the iCloud files or periodically check the web interface for recently deleted files to be sure you are not deleting files you expect to retain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my experimentation :

I tried downloading a test file (which worked). It showed up right on top of the important file (of which I was talking about above) when I clicked the circle with an arrow pointing down next to the address bar.

When I clicked it, it opened the file (a .docx file) IN Safari, not in Files!

I then went to Files app and saw that the file has been downloaded in iCloud > Downloads as the other one before it had been moved.

I went back to Safari and deleted the test file from Safari download *list*. When I went back to Files, the test file was still there!

I tried doing the same thing again but moved test file 2 (still .docx) out of iCloud > Downloads and dropped it in iCloud right after I downloaded it to Safari downloads. Guess what? It was still in Safari downloads!

Most bewildering stuff: I removed test file 2 from iCloud > Downloads and from everywhere on Files app (I searched). And... **It was still staying unmoving in Safari download list and I could still open it normally**!!!

I then made a test file 3 because test file and test file 2 weren't in both Safari downloads and Files.

I tried sending a sample email to my other email account with test file 3 as an attachment to the email. It did work and I could normally open it as a .docx file as a preview. *Note: I dragged test file 3 from Safari downloads to Mail app*.

I then did the same with test file 4 but selecting the file by clicking on the sheet of paper symbol (on top of the keyboard when typing an email in Mail app). It also worked the same.

Comment: This doesn;t really answer the question - it should be made more understandable and be in the question. Also the previous answers were here before you wrote this - how are they wrong

Comment: @mmmmmm I was asked to put this as an answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457324/does-deleting-a-file-in-safari-downloads-also-deletes-it-in-files-app/457337?noredirect=1#comment666673_457337

Comment: @mmmmmm the previous answers aren't wrong but their authors asked me to test out things, which I originally did in the question